# ScheduledExecutorService stops working even when all exceptions are caught

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have `ScheduledExecutorService` set to execute every minute. My command catches all exceptions to prevent executor service to stop working. However, for some reason, it sometimes stops working (let's say once every few days, probably when application has more traffic).

My method starting executor service:

```
public void startExecutor(ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
   Runnable job = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doJob();
        }
    };
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(job, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

ScheduledExecutorService is initialized by Dropwizard this way:

```
@Override
public void run(NuvrProjectsAndRecordingsConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = environment.lifecycle().scheduledExecutorService("job").build();
}
```

Dropwizard creates `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` implementation with `corePoolSize` equal to 1.

The `doJob()` method catches all exceptions:

```
private void doJob() {
    try {
        worker.process();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Cannot perform job, will retry", e);
    }
}
```

And the `process()` method handles regular exceptions and has `finally` section:

```
public void process() {
    try {
        // some hard stuff
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Processing of job failed", ex);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unknown error during recording processor", e);
    } finally {
        // clean after processing
    }
}
```

What is interesting is that sometimes Exception is thrown from `finally` section.

Since all operations are protected by global catch-exception section - why do executor service stops working?

Comment: "*sometimes Exception is thrown from `finally` section"* What do you have in that block?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to catch all Throwables as the Exception class doesn't include subclass Error.